# java.net.UnknownHostException dockerized mysql from spring boot application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, docker, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application and dockerized mysql db.
My docker container is up and result of **docker ps** command below.

```
cf7936857c6f        mysql:5.6           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        3306/tcp            mysql-standalone
```

application properties file configuration here;

> spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://mysql-standalone:3306/test
>
> spring.datasource.username = sa
>
> spring.datasource.password = password

I have run mysql docker container like this

```
docker run --name mysql-standalone -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test -e MYSQL_USER=sa -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:5.6
```

And when I try to start my spring boot application on IDE
I have faced

> java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql-standalone

Is there any missing configuration in my property file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run mysql container exposing the port as below.

> docker run --name mysql-standalone -e
>   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test -e MYSQL_USER=sa
>   -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:5.6

And in you spring boot `application.properties` file, modify as below.

> spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false

Don't forget to add `useSSL=false`, else you might get below error.

```
Spring Boot: Jdbc javax.net.ssl.SSLException: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify
```

Answer (score 15):

Since this is not container to container communication you have to bind the MySQL port to a port in the host:

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name mysql-standalone -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test -e MYSQL_USER=sa -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:5.6
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And point to `localhost`:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me. Actually I was wondering why should i use the name of the container, now i know why.